Golang program crashes (segmentation fault) when running on ARMv7 rev 5 (v7l) OpenWRT router
I am trying to compiler a cross-platform in Golang to run on OpenWRT Router (GDock). The target system is:

Linux OpenWrt 5.15.118 #0 SMP Wed Jul 5 20:20:32 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux


model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 26.81
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5
I wrote a small program that print "Hello world" with only import "fmt" module. The program below:

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

I compile it by:
GO=linux GOARM=7,softfloat GOARCH=arm /usr/local/go/bin/go build .
I checked the file with file command:
main: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=z6RADCEu-jOWczIr0anP/cqhqMt2UfXF1iAnzuTKC/uwGWq8e4UU7E-hUo7T7S/eNInvO8n3j0q7bTGVsJ7, with debug_info, not stripped
Current system, that I used to compile:
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-107-generic #117~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 30 10:35:57 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Golang version:
go version go1.22.2 linux/amd64
The program works on Ubuntu:
./main 
Hello world!

However, when I copy the program to router, I got Segmentation Fault. I tried to copy a router busybox and check with file command, the result I got is:
busybox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1, no section header
I searched everywhere on the Internet and could not find the answer, some results resolved for CGO. But it's not my problem!
Why I got segmentation fault? I can not debug because of tidy resource on the router.
How can I fixed it?

It is strange that a program compiles for ARM runs on your AMD64 linux machine. Also strange that it is shown as statically linked on ubuntu, but dynamically linked on the router. What are you exactly doing, what are the sha256 hashes of the various binaries?

Are you using FTP to upload the compiled binary to the router? If yes, make sure you first switch transfer mode to binary and retry.

Apparently similar question.

@eik there are 2 files, busybox is a dynamically linked binary and my file that is statically linked binary

BTW, GO=linux is probably not what you think as the Go toolchain recognizes GOOS, not just GO.

@kostix I used a software of openwrt to upload file

If you have a solution to your problem, post it as an answer! You can accept it to mark the question as solved.

The problem comes from my ftp, I checked sha2sum and realize my file corrupted when upload to server. So, I use the difference sftp server and checksum to make sure file is not corrupted then it worked!
